# Vertically center divs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm setting up a one page website, I want to vertically center a containing div within a div with 100% viewport height, currently I have -

```
function vertmiddle() {
    var height = $('.vertmiddle').height();
    var windowheight = $(window).height();
    var vertmiddle = ((windowheight) - (height)) / 2;
    vertmiddle = parseInt(vertmiddle) + 'px';
    $(".vertmiddle").css('margin-top',vertmiddle);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    vertmiddle();
    $(window).bind('resize', vertmiddle);
});
```

Edit, Here is an example of the HTLM I'm using as well -

```
<section id="community" class="full">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="vertmiddle">
        content
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

It's working fine but all of my containing divs are getting the same margin amount because they all use the same class and it's just using the first div on the pages height.

How can I set it up so each containing div has the correct margin. I can probably make this work with unique classes and just repeat the script but I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do it.

Sorry if I'm unclear I'm new posting here.

thanks

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation for [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)? You need to loop through the matches if you want them positioned differently.

Comment: In vertmiddle(), try iterating on all elements with given class and then use "$(this)" for calculation.

Comment: you should use different class names or different ids for each containing div

Comment: I looked into .each() and couldn't work out how to implement it looks like it will lead to a solution I'm just not that great with jQuery yet so it's a lot of trial and error

Comment: why are you using JQuery to vertically center the divs ??

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
function vertmiddle() {
  $('.vertmiddle').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'left' : '50%',
        'top' : '50%',
        'margin-left' : -$(this).width()/2,
        'margin-top' : -$(this).height()/2
    });
}
```

Or may be you try this

```
 $('.vertmiddle').css({
        position:'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('.vertmiddle').outerWidth())/2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('.vertmiddle').outerHeight())/2
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works, but you will need to add id attributes to your HTML. I have found trying to call jQuery methods that measure window objects using classes to be very buggy, where the same methods used on ids never give me any problems. Anyway, here is one approach...

```
<section id="community" class="full">
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <div id="content" class="vertmiddle">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

function vertMiddle(){
  var element_height = $('#content').height();
  var element_offset = (window.innerHeight - element_height) / 2;
  $('#content').css('margin-top', element_offset +'px');
}

$(document).ready( function(){
    vertMiddle();
    $(window).on('resize', vertMiddle);
});
```

Here is a [working JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ephiphany/6md5vzdu/)